# How can we make query return all the rows when IN operator and BETWEEN value is null

Tags: java, mysql

am little confused

I have a query where I have to get some customer values for which, will get some customer id's as input, it would look something like this

```
SELECT * FROM CUTOMER WHERE CUTOMER_ID IN ('1','2');
```

but sometimes the the customer id's will not be selected in that case, have to return all the rows.

I have similar kind of problem with between also for start date and end date, sometimes start date and end date are provided but sometimes when they are not selected I should return all the rows

can someone help me to handle case ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your intentions. Do you mean that you need to filter by `customer_id` field, but sometimes it's given (i.e. `1, 2`) and sometimes it's not and so you need to return all rows (i.e. `select * from customer`)?

Comment: yes.... it has to return everything

Comment: Where do you get the customer_id list?

Comment: @user2572003 Can you show us your java code?

Comment: i can write with if else statements but am thinking a way out to include this is sql query itself

Comment: Is it not allowed/possible to build the where clause dynamically depending on the given values?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a LEFT JOIN. First you have to write a query that returns all the values you are searching for:

```
SELECT 1 AS CUSTOMER_ID
UNION ALL SELECT 2
```

(this can be dynamic) then you can use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
  s.CUSTOMER_ID,
  c.*
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS CUSTOMER_ID
   UNION ALL SELECT 2) s
  LEFT JOIN CUTOMER c
  ON s.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID
```

the left join will return all rows from the first query, and only the rows from the second query that have a match, otherwise it will return nulls.